# Web scraping research abstracts - issues with maintaining bullet points in output

Tags: python, pandas, text, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm web scraping various research abstracts and creating a dataset.  When I try to do this for a PCORI abstract, I'm able to get what I need, however when the text has bullet points, the bullet points:

1. are not in my output, and
2. the indenting associated with the bullet point are not either

I'm a bit of a newbie and while I did look around for other code, I surprising could not find anyone else with the same issue. The example I'm working with is: https://www.pcori.org/research-results/2013/testing-new-ways-schedule-appointments-community-health-centers-help-patients

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

out = []

urlsummary ='https://www.pcori.org/research-results/2013/testing-new-ways- 
schedule-appointments-community-health-centers-help-patients'
html = requests.get(urlsummary).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

abstract = soup.find(class_='pane pane--node').get_text(" ")
about = abstract.split('What was the research about?')[1]
project_status = soup.find(class_='field field-name-field-award- 
status').get_text(" ")


data = {'About': about, 'abstract': abstract, 'Status': project_status}
out.append(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print (df)

df.to_excel('PCORI_Results.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that whenever you use `.get_text(" ")`, you strip out the html. In this case, it strips out the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags that create the bullet points.